# What happens if I make an async ajax call after a sync ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, blocking

I was wondering what will happen if I make 2 ajax calls one after the other on different events.

Lets say, I have two buttons, on click on one , I make a blocking ajax call, which lets say returns the result after 2 minutes.

On the click of the other I make a async ajax call , which returns after an average of 1 minute.

If I click button 1 and button 2 one after the other, would both ajax calls take place, or would the second call be stopped until the first (blocked) one returns?

I feel that both will take place if the browser connection limit has not reached.
Otherwise , the ajax calls will wait.

I can always try creating a simple page and testing this, but want to know , what experts here feel.

Thanks

Comment: If you click button 1 you can't use the UI for 2 minutes. This is why we hate blocking ajax calls

Comment: what if the event is not a button click , but some other custom event which is triggerred lets say on a timeout?

Comment: haha.. getting hyped are we?? Yes I understand the shitty implications now. Just that before I used something like this in an application I wanted to get my due diligence done.. :) and this is a valid question , dont understand why would you want to downvote it.

Comment: (for the record, i didn't downvote this question) 
The question itself is not a bad one, but in order to create a situation where this becomes problematic, you need to deliberately create a situation with unsafe cross-thread calls, which isn't exactly considered good practice ;)
+1 for the eagerness to learn. (upvoted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sync (blocking) ajax call will block you from starting the async ajax call before it finishes.

it might be more interesting to look at what would happen the other way around, but then again, i don't think i've ever uncovered synchronous Ajax calls in any web application i have seen. (with good reason)

Comment: what if the event is not a button click , but some other custom event which is triggerred lets say on a timeout?

Comment: the timeout event will not occur until the blocking call has finished.
if the calls originate from separate threads, they will not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to click on the 2nd button if the click on the 1st button is synchronous ajax call. The browser blocks on synchronous ajax calls that are bind to a button.

Comment: what if the event is not a button click , but some other custom event which is triggerred lets say on a timeout?